# How to stream http content to a file and a buffer?

Tags: go

I want to copy the data from an http response to a file and a buffer.

However, I can't quite figure this out.

Initially I had this:

```
func DownloadS3(hash string, cluster Cluster, tok *oauth.Token, offset, length int64, f *os.File) ([]byte, error) {

    // ... other code not shown ...

    resp, err = DoHTTPRequest("GET", s3tok.URL, nil, reqhdr, defaultClientTimeout)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error downloading from cluster:", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != 200 && resp.StatusCode != 206 {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Create buffer to return actual content
    buf := make([]byte, resp.ContentLength)

    // This actually does copy the whole downloaded data to the file as
    // expected.  However, I didn't expect io.CopyBuffer to not use the entire
    // buffer.  It ends up returning a portion of the file.
    _, err = io.CopyBuffer(f, resp.Body, buf)

    return buf, err
}
```

So what I want actually is something like

```
_, err = io.CopyBuffer(f, io.TeeReader(resp.Body, buf), nil)
```

Only, I cant pass buf into TeeReader as it doesn't implement the writer interface.  I'm sure there is a proper method but I can't find it as I fumble
around looking for an efficient way to do this.

How do I do this without allocating buffer after buffer.  I was trying to be efficient. i.e. It seems silly to write the file and read it back.

What I've tried but doesn't work as expected.

```
    // Create buffer to return actual content
    buf := make([]byte, resp.ContentLength)
    _, err = io.CopyBuffer(f, io.TeeReader(resp.Body,bytes.NewBuffer(buf)), nil)
    return buf, nil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make the (other) answer clear and complete: it's not [`io.TeeReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader)'s fault that you were not able to copy the complete body to file and have it as a [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer), but it's entirely [`io.CopyBuffer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#CopyBuffer)'s fault.

[`io.Copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) is the knight and shining armor, the one who keeps on copying until the whole input is consumed:

> Copy copies from src to dst until either EOF is reached on src or an error occurs.

So an equivalently good solution using `io.TeeReader()`:

```
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, resp.ContentLength))
_, err = io.Copy(f, io.TeeReader(resp.Body, buf))
return buf.Bytes(), err
```

Using [`bytes.NewBuffer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer) like this you can pre-allocate the necessary buffer and avoid reallocation and copying (which makes it faster). Of course you can use this with [`io.MultiWriter()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter) too.

Comment: Thanks, I actually like this solution better.  It seems to be quite a bit faster.  Although both this answer and @Cerise Limon's work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Use [io.MultiWriter](https://godoc.org/io#MultiWriter) and [bytes.Buffer](https://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer) to grab a copy of the data as the data is written to the file:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
_, err := io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(f, &buf), resp.Body)
return buf.Bytes(), err
```

There is no guarantee that io.CopyBuffer will write to the entire buffer. The current implementation will only use the entire buffer when the entire response body is read in a single call to io.Reader.Read. In your example, it takes more than one read to slurp on the entire response body.

Comment: Thanks that has fixed it.    Using ioutil.Readall to a buffer also worked but I think what you have may be more efficient?  Anyway the bug I had with the CopyBuffer has now gone.